# purrr::Compose or any alternative to reduce the run time for a long nested function in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, iteration, purrr

Problem: I have several (10+) custom functions, each defining a step in the workflow. I want  to run a nested function of these steps over a large data frame for n (50+) periods iteratively. My current function achieves the result but it is too slow and not very elegant.

**Example Input**

```
 id x_1975 z_1975
1  1      1     NA
2  2      2     NA
3  3      3     NA
4  4      4     NA
5  5      5     NA
```

**Step 1:**
Compare initial x values (x_1975) against a cutoff=3. If x is greater than 3, then the z value should be "Y".

**Step 2:**
If z value is "Y", then x value in next year should be x times 2. Otherwise, it should be x times 5. Although the z values can be skipped altogether, I need the categorical column to create summary stats.

**Note:**
The data set I am working with has 20 variables that need to be calculated based on some similar logics.

**Desired Output**

```
 id x_1975 z_1975 x_1976 z_1976 x_1977 z_1977 x_1978
1  1      1   <NA>      5      Y     10      Y     20
2  2      2   <NA>     10      Y     20      Y     40
3  3      3   <NA>     15      Y     30      Y     60
4  4      4      Y      8      Y     16      Y     32
5  5      5      Y     10      Y     20      Y     40
6  6      6      Y     12      Y     24      Y     48
```

What I have tried:

1. Tried setting the data in long format. But found it complicated to iterate over rows.
2. Pre-allocated all columns with appropriate class. That reduced run time a little although not enough.
3. Have been trying to use purrr::compose to nest all the functions. But I am not being able to make it work.

## Reproducible Example

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Create Data Frame
    n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                  x_1975=seq(1,6,1),
                  z_1975=NA)
cut_off <- 3

# Functions

# Set a value for "z_" variables in period t by comparing "x_" value in period t against the the cut_off value.

func_1 <- function(dat,yr){
  # pre-define variables
  z <- paste0("z_",yr)
  x <- paste0("x_",yr)
  
  # Caclulate values for "z_" in period t
  dat <- dat %>% mutate(!!sym(z):=
                          case_when(!!sym(x)>cut_off ~ "Y",
                                    TRUE~as.character(NA)
  ))
}

# Calculate the value for "x_" variables in period t+1 based on "z_" variables in period t.

func_2 <- function(dat,yr){
# pre-define variables 
  x <- paste0("x_",yr+1)
  x_lag <- paste0("x_",yr)
  z <- paste0("z_",yr)

# Calculate "x_" value for t+1
  dat <- dat %>% mutate(!!sym(x):=case_when(
    !!sym(z)=="Y"~!!sym(x_lag)*2,
    TRUE~!!sym(x_lag)*5
  ))
}

# Join function 1 and function 2 together. The joined function needs to iterate over the `dat` from beginning year to ending year

joined_func <- function(dat,beginning,ending){
  for (year in seq(beginning,ending,1)){
    dat <- func_1(dat,year)
# Output of step 1 is used as input for step 2
    dat <- func_2(dat,year)
  }
  return(dat)
}

# Run the code from 1975 to 2025.The data_output has the desired output, but need to reduce runtime. 
data_output <- joined_func(dat,1975,1977)


# Tried to use the compose function from purrr. but getting error.
my_funs <- c(func_1, func_2)
f1 <- invoke(compose, my_funs)
joined_func_2 <- function(dat,beginning,ending){
  for (year in seq(beginning,ending,1)){
    dat <- f1(dat,year=year)
  }
}
data_output_2 <- joined_func_2(dat,1975,1977)

# Error message:
# Error in f1(dat, year = year) : unused argument (year = year).
```

**Questions**

a) how do I make purrr::compose work? b) any other way to achieve efficiency?

Would really appreciate if someone could help me on this!

Comment: Just give the data, and then the results you expect. elaborate the steps to get the specific results and someone will give you another way to get to the results needed.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Elaborated the steps and modified code to reflect the idea behind the problem. The actual data contains a lot more variables similar to "x_" and "z_" and lot more steps similar to "func_1" and "func_2", adding to the runtime.

Comment: The notion here should be *I have this dataset. How can I get the results using R* and then you explain the logic. No one will go through your code. We will try to get the results from the explained logic and not from the code

Comment: You have an error in your function definitions. the formals for `fun_1/2` are `dat` and `yr` while your composed function you are trying to pass to an invalid argument `year`. If you fix this, you will probably run into another error. I dont think `compose` was intended to be used such that arguments could be passed to each function independently. You can verify this by checking the source code of `compose` - it will only use the formals of the first function called.

Comment: @JustinLandis, I suspected that too. Thank you for the answer.